# loopCount and threadCount in user.property file in Azure pipeline using Azure Load test

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines, performance-testing, load-testing

I am trying to pass the loopCount and threadCount values from the jmeter user.properties
file in azure pipeline in the Azure load test.

It is still taking the default value of 1 and just running 1 thread and 1 loop. I have been following the link
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-configure-user-properties?pivots=experience-azp"

Jmeter View for Thread Porperties:

[image]

And i have added these lines in user.property file:

[image: User.Property]

Have also added this in my YAMl file :

properties:
userPropertyFile: 'user.properties'

Not sure where it is going wrong..Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not initialized properties have default value of `1` to it means that JMeter doesn't pick up your .properties file at all.

If your file is called `user.property` the correct YAML syntax would be:

```
properties:
  userPropertyFile: user.property
```

More information:

- [Use JMeter user properties with Azure Load Testing Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-configure-user-properties?pivots=experience-pipelines)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: It is called user.properties only.